# youtrack issues with shortcuts and reording issues

Tags: youtrack

im using youtrack to manage my tasks in the project.

The problem is that other users than me cant reorder issues in the backlog - even though they have admin permisions on this project and I cant dissable shotrcuts - for example Im from poland and right_alt+c is ć and I would like to use it in the task description but I simply cant cause alt+c is apply command window :/

Comment: For the shortcut problem one of the workarounds described in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-3412 may be applicable; it depends on the version of youtrack you're using.